# Discussion on when is the solution of the system $y' = Ay$ bounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

Given the matrix $A$:

$$A=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & -2 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

$a)$ Find the general solution for the system of first order linear differential equations $y' = Ay$. (HINT: you should get 4 independent eigenvectors).

After solving $a)$ you should be able to answer $b)$.

$b)$ Find out for which positive integer $n$ the following statement holds:

> Let C be an $n \times n$ invertible matrix with pure imaginary eigenvalues. If $y : \Re \rightarrow \Re^n$ is a solution of $y' = Cy$ then $y$ is limited (**EDIT**: what is meant is that $y$ is bounded).

**What I have tried:**

$a)$ The characteristic polynomial of $A$ (let me skip showing the determinant; the result is correct) is:

$$\Delta (\lambda) = \lambda^4 + 2\lambda^2 + 1$$

Which roots are:

$$\lambda_1 = i$$
$$\lambda_2 = -i$$

Where each has multiplicity of 2.

The general solution is (let me skip the algebraic steps; I will provide more details if you want to):

$y(x) = c_1\left[
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    -2i \\
    -1 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}xe^{ix} + \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 \\
    i \\
    -1 \\
    i \\
    \end{pmatrix} e^{ix}\right] + c_2\left[\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    2i \\
    -1 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}xe^{-ix} + \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    i \\
    1 \\
    i \\
    \end{pmatrix} e^{-ix}\right]$

**EDIT:** The above equation may be wrong. The correct answer may be:

$y(x) = c_1
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    -2i \\
    -1 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}xe^{ix} + c_2\begin{pmatrix}
    -1 \\
    i \\
    -1 \\
    i \\
    \end{pmatrix} e^{ix} + c_3\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    2i \\
    -1 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}xe^{-ix} + c_4\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    i \\
    1 \\
    i \\
    \end{pmatrix} e^{-ix}$

$b)$ I don't see what is meant here by saying 'then $y$ is limited'. My guess is that what is limited is the number of independent eigenvectors; Thus for our case $n=4$ and the statement holds. Am I right?

An explanation on $b)$ would be appreciated.

Comment: No, limited as in bounded. As in, there exists some $R$ such that the euclidean norm $\|y\| < R$ for all $x$

Comment: You have a typo in the expression for $y(x)$; $t$ should be $x$. And not enough free constants,; there should be four.

Comment: @encore I agree on the typo, let me fix it. However I do not agree on your free constants comment. Note I get two eigenvalues each having multiplicity of 2.

Comment: @JD_PM A $4\times 4$ linear system is equivalent to a fourth order ODE in one variable and there you need four free constants. Just ask yourself, if you multiplied $xe^{ix}$ by 2 in your expression, would it still solve $y'=Ay$. The answer is yes, it would.

Comment: @encore Please look at my edit. Is it what you meant?

Comment: That looks better, we have to eigenvectors and two generalized eigenvectors. Where did this problem come from because "y is limited" is not standard terminology. Is it asking if the solutions are bounded for all time?

Comment: @Moo I am also confused on what is meant by "y is limited". Note this is a translation from Dutch (made by Google Translator). Literally it says 'dan is y begrensd'

Comment: @JD_PM Yup, that's good.

Comment: @JD_PM: If you convert the imaginary to trig terms, you have cosine and sine sums for each variable and those look like they might be bounded (check this by analysis). I think the translation likely got corrupted and this meant this is what it meant. I used the translator http://webtranslation.paralink.com/Dutch-English-Translation/, and it says that means ... "Then Y is bounded".

Comment: @Moo thanks for the translation help! OK so checking whether y(x) is bounded for certain values of $n$ is the issue. You proposed using Euler's formula to get sin and cos terms. I am going to think about it.

Comment: $y$ is limited is indeed not standard terminology but I have experienced translations from I think french like this, which is why I was sure in my comment

Comment: For boundedness you will need $c_1=c_3=0$.

Comment: @encore You pointed at the two non-periodic terms of the solution. I see there's a relation between boundedness and periodicity; unbounded terms are non-periodic and the other way around. Then in our case we should have $n=2$ to get a bounded solution (and not $n=4$). What do you all think?

Comment: @JD_PM You need to figure our for what $n$ there *cannot* be a multiple purely imaginary root. Your example shows there can be one for $n\geq 4$. So it looks like the only way to be sure there isn't one is to take $n\in\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: @encore I am afraid I do not see why you said 'So it looks like'. Could you please clarify?